# How to describe request body?

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a WCF restful web service.  Generally, each of my endpoints can be described by /service/help perfectly because they only make use of query strings as input parameters.  So for instance, I have the following simple function:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "customer?name={name}", Method = "POST")]
public void customer(string name)
```

This shows up in /service/help as:

```
Service at http://localhost:7000/service/customer?name={NAME}
```

Unfortunately, I can't do this for two cases:

1. Endpoints with incredibly long values (query string gets truncated)
2. Endpoints with sensitive data (password parameter getting logged by IIS)

For these two cases, I know need to pass a request body.  Changing my function to:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "customer", Method = "POST")]
public void customer(Stream requestBody)
```

Now /service/help only returns

```
Service at http://localhost:7000/service/customer
```

If I click on the link and navigate to /service/help/operations/customer, I also don't receive any useful information:

```
The Request body is a byte stream
```

How do I describe the XML/jSON structure of the request body to the consumer of the API?  Can I somehow leverage /service/help or am I forced to use an API document?

Comment: why would a `name` value be so long that the URL becomes truncated? wouldn't that be an invalid input, deserving of a `400`ish error?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought: I would say that decorating all of your API endpoints with in-url arguments is only useful some of the time, and that you really ought to build a full API doc for your API where you've provided information on the expected input and output for requests like /service/customer.

Also, why would a name ever be so long that a url becomes truncated? If i were you, i'd consider a 1000 char long name to be invalid input, deserving of an immediate `400: bad request` response